# Which icons have matching width / height ? Material Design icons are uneven

Tags: icons, material-design, alignment

If you look at the containing vector of Material Design Icons, this is what makes the icons match in size. However the vectors of the content inside are not all the same sizes and follow no standard, therefore the icons are jagged when they are lined up vertically or horizontally.

Here is an example of the containing vector:

[image]

Here is an example of the content box:

[image]

When placed side by side with other icons, the sizes of the content are all different sizes. It creates a design problem and is not pleasing to the eye.

Is there a solution for getting the content of Material Design Icons the same width / and or height?
If not what other free icons solve this problem?

Comment: The solution to this issue is to not design with every icon in the exact same size, but to design with every icon in the same balance. Some icons can be very heavy due to their fills, and some very light because they don't take a lot of space (chevrons, for example). It's quite tricky to design with this in mind, hence why very commonplace icons are still being perfected. You can manually check all icons you use and edit them if you think it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As Wanda has already replied, icons are designed with Visual Balance in mind. If you look at Material Design guide or any icon guide there is square and then there's wide and tall. The wide and the tall icons exceed the basic square to some degree. A wide icon will be shorter than the square height, so in order to compensate it goes wider and extends beyonds the square in about the same amount. Same goes for the tall icon but in the other way. However, because of the stated problem, designers do try to stick to the square as much as possible.

If you want all equally sized as the container, then may be get the SVG files and edit them yourself. In order to maintain the visual balance you can try using Outline icons instead of Filled.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with Material Design Icons, however [Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons have a fixed width option you set by adding `fa-fw` to the icons class. They have both free and paid icons.

I'm using Fontawesome icons in my new [Tree](https://clibu-tree-test-app.netlify.com/) which uses Material Design.

Comment: The issue isn't whether or not the icons come with fixed width, it is whether the content inside the container matches the width. Just because all of the containers have the same or matching widths doesn't mean the icons will align or match width.  See images above.